# add element to array of struct in C++ encountered "error no match for ‘operator=’"

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-keyword

My code was

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Numbers{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct NumbersArray{
    int size;
    Numbers *numbers;
};
int main(){
    NumbersArray numArr;
    numArr.size = 10;
    numArr.numbers = new Numbers[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Numbers *num = new Numbers;
        num->a = i * 3 + 0;
        num->b = i * 3 + 1;
        num->c = i * 3 + 2;
        numArr.numbers[i] = num;
    }
}
```

The basic idea is I create a struct called Numbers which contains 3 numbers and put it in a wrapper struct called NumbersArray.
And when I compile it with g++, I got error message

```
testArrayStruct.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
testArrayStruct.cc:23:27: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Numbers’ and ‘Numbers*’)
         numArr.numbers[i] = num;
                           ^
testArrayStruct.cc:23:27: note: candidate is:
testArrayStruct.cc:4:8: note: Numbers& Numbers::operator=(const Numbers&)
 struct Numbers{
        ^
testArrayStruct.cc:4:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Numbers*’ to ‘const Numbers&’
```

Just ignore memory management here.
I cant figure it how to add elements to the array.

Comment: Read up on pointers vs values in c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be (ignoring your memory management as you asked):

```
numArr.numbers[i] = *num;
```

Instead of

```
numArr.numbers[i] = num;
```

since `numArr.numbers[i]` is of type `Numbers` while `num` is of type `Numbers*`.

**EDIT:**

The error actually tells you that there is no `operator=` to perform assignment of `Numbers *` to `Numbers`. So actually you could implement your own `operator=` which would perform such operation:

```
Numbers& operator=(Numbers& left, const Numbers * const right)
{
    if (right != NULL) // or nullptr for C++11
    {
        left = *right;
    }
    return left;
}
```

With such implementation your original code would also compile.

One remark regarding the memory management. There is no real need to allocate new `Numbers` inside the for loop since you copy that content into the `numArr.numbers` anyway. So you could write it that way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    numArr.numbers[i].a = i * 3 + 0;
    numArr.numbers[i].b = i * 3 + 1;
    numArr.numbers[i].c = i * 3 + 2;
}
```

Comment: `numArr.numbers[i] = *num;` will leak `num`.

Comment: @zenith Why down voting? He clearly asked to ignore the memory management and help him understand why there is the compilation error.

Comment: Not my downvote. And yeah I didn't notice the OP asked to ignore the  memory management issues.

Comment: @zenith You shouldn't have deleted your answer. Sorry for my rude comment there (I deleted it) I just thought that it was your down vote.

Comment: Don't worry I'm writing another answer that doesn't have the same content as yours :)

Comment: @japreiss Let the OP to decide what will confuse him and what won't. Don't write silly comments unless giving a solid explanation of why it is or why it is not a good answer. Comments like "please don't follow this advice, follow mine" are childish.

Comment: Downvoter here. My issue was your `operator=` signature. IMO overloading operators in a non-recommended way will cause problems down the line (principle of least astonishment). To be fair it does make the original code compile, but the original code is wrong.

Comment: @dan it is you right to down vote. I am OK with such reason. The point is that `operator=` wasn't my recommendation but rather a remark for potential option to solve issues with assignments of not identical types. But I agree that it wasn't clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are practising on the wrong things, and you will just
pick up bad habits this way. C++ thrive on value semantics,
focus on that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Numbers {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

using NumbersArray = vector<Numbers>;

int main()
{
    NumbersArray numArr;
    numArr.resize(10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Numbers num;
        num.a = i * 3 + 0;
        num.b = i * 3 + 1;
        num.c = i * 3 + 2;
        numArr[i] = num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to add elements to the array

You can't.

When you said `new Numbers[10]` you created an array of ten default-initialized elements. An array can't resize itself after initialization.

It sounds like you should be using `std::vector`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<Numbers> numArr;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Numbers num;
        num.a = i * 3 + 0;
        num.b = i * 3 + 1;
        num.c = i * 3 + 2;
        numArr.push_back(num);
    }

    std::cout << "numArr contains " << numArr.size() << " elements." << std::endl;
}
```

Now you can add as many elements as you like and don't have to keep track of `size` etc. yourself. `std::vector` will resize itself when it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. You are try to assign a pointer of an object to the object itself. The following one fixes it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Numbers{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

struct NumbersArray{
    int size;
    Numbers **numbers;
};
int main(){
    NumbersArray numArr;
    numArr.size = 10;
    numArr.numbers = new Numbers* [10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        Numbers *num = new Numbers;
        num->a = i * 3 + 0;
        num->b = i * 3 + 1;
        num->c = i * 3 + 2;
        numArr.numbers[i] = num;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code compiles, it is not a good solution. This allocates all 10 `Numbers` objects in separate heap blocks. OP's original code would allocate one block of memory for all 10 objects, which is preferable unless there's a reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

This is the important part of your error message:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Numbers’ and ‘Numbers*’)
```

You are trying to assign a pointer to `Numbers` into a `Numbers` value. The rest of the error message is not helpful.

Assuming you don't want to change the `NumbersArray` class like all the other answers are suggesting, your inner loop should look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Numbers num;
    num.a = i * 3 + 0;
    num.b = i * 3 + 1;
    num.c = i * 3 + 2;
    numArr.numbers[i] = num;
}
```

Read about values and pointers in C++.